# Python Not Waiting for MATLAB to Finish

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am interfacing a small MATLAB script with Python via the `subprocess` module. As follows:

```
cmd='(matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "optimizer;quit;")'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=None,stdout=None,shell=True)
#subprocess.Popen.wait(p)
#p.wait()
print "DONE?"
```

But "DONE" is being printed even before MATLAB starts! My entire code past it is breaking because of this.

I have tried:

- Using os.system() calls (This is where I started, but I read on SO that its deprecated)
- Using `p.wait()` and `subprocess.Popen.wait`. Both don't work.
- Using a manual pause of 3 minutes (Max. time MATLAB takes to finish on average) *Super Sloppy*.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had a similar thing happen in my ASP.NET MVC page when trying to call MATLAB. Are you running any specific function in MATLAB, or do you just want to turn it on?

Comment: @IronMan84 I am unable to get a mathematical code work in NumPy so I am exporting my matrices to a csv file, reading it in MATLAB, computing and exporting the answer to a csv file and reading it back in Python.

Comment: What happens if you remove the parenthesis?

Comment: @mgilson around cmd? Nothing happened, same problem.

Comment: follow-up -- Is the command `matlab` some sort of daemon?  i.e., does that command run and complete right away?  What happens if you replace the command `matlab` with a different command -- Say `echo "foo"; sleep 10; echo "bar"`?  Does that return right away?

Comment: Check to see if 'matlab' has a command-line option to not behave this way. It might. (it looks the 'matlab' process being started is exiting after sending a request to another process, or otherwise acting in a daemon-launcher-like way)

Comment: "Using `p.wait()` and `subprocess.Popen.wait`. Both don't work." What does "don't work" mean?

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop", "-r", "quit;"])
print "DONE", retcode
```

Split the command arguments accordingly, use only options that you actually require (no need for `shell=True`, for example), use the function that directly does what you are after (`call`), i.e., call and wait for completion.

Depending on your installation (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html), Matlab may be launched in a way such that it immediately quits. To handle that, add "-wait" to your argument list.

Comment: Nope. Neither solutions worked. As I mentioned in the other answer, I have an infinite try, except loop and it is still entering the except loop.

Comment: Entering the "except loop" ? What is that ? I assume you meant something in the form of except block, and then it seems you have some error starting matlab then.

Comment: No, I meant. I have something like this:
try:
matlab command. 
except:
sleep for 1s and continue.
No matter what I do, it keeps entering the except block.

Comment: That is exactly what I said. It shouldn't enter the except block except if you had an error running the command.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, it does exit once I see MATLAB exit. Then, everything works well.

Comment: What is your operating system and Matlab version ? This works just fine under Linux and OSX with the Matlab versions I have, and under Windows you are supposed to add "-wait".

Comment: I am simultaneously working on Windows and Linux. It is working in neither.

Comment: You forgot to mention which Matlab version you have.

Comment: Linux:2011, Windows:2012b.

Comment: Please run this exact program: http://pastebin.com/2HnWw782 (don't touch anything, just run it through python) and paste your exact output somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Start Matlab with the "-wait" flag. From the documenation:

"MATLAB is started by a separate starter program which normally launches MATLAB and then immediately quits. Using this option tells the starter program not to quit until MATLAB has terminated. This option is useful when you need to process the results from MATLAB in a script. Calling MATLAB with this option blocks the script from continuing until the results are generated."

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment, let me answer your question with what I did for my application, that had a similar process to yours (albeit in C#). Instead of trying to force your process to wait for MATLAB to finish up (which is obviously not working right now), just wait for that CSV file to be written to. If you're worried about possibly having duplicates, then just append the current date and time to the end of the file, and that should do the trick.

Comment: That's my solution right now. Infinite loop waiting for the file to appear.